# MVC3,Razor,Question about different Layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, layout, razor

Look the following image:

I can not submit a image now,pls click [code image](http://resource.520.cn/img/q.jpg) to see the image.

I set a _ViewStart,_Layout and relative files in "Login" file that are different from "Shared" file.What I want is to display a different layout when open page "/Login/Index" and others display the default layout.And it works well as my expect.
But when I use a section to load a "js" file in "index.cshtml",the web show errors "defined thd following sections,but not for layout“~/Views/Login/_Layout.cshtml”appear:“HeadJs”。"

the following codes is a part of Login/Layout:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @if (IsSectionDefined("Meta"))
    {
        RenderSection("Meta", false);
    }
    <link href="@GlobalVal.__siteResource/Css/Global/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    @if (IsSectionDefined("Css"))
    {
        RenderSection("Css", false);
    }
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var GlobalVal={__siteHome:"@(GlobalVal.__siteHome)",__siteResource:"@(GlobalVal.__siteResource)"};
    </script>
    <script src="@GlobalVal.__siteResource/js/Lib/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    @if (IsSectionDefined("HeadJs"))
    {
        RenderSection("HeadJs", false);
    }
</head>
```

and the following codes is "/login/index.cshtml":

```
@using TJK.Model;
@model MemberUser
@section HeadJs {
<script src="@GlobalVal.__siteResource/Js/Lib/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@GlobalVal.__siteResource/Js/Lib/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"     type="text/javascript"></script>
}
```

Comment: I find the problem.
Use @RenderSection("HeadJs", false) instead of RenderSection("HeadJs", false);

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your sections all the way down to the top master page.

Basically doing RenderSection("Myname", false);

Comment: I have define a new layout in Login file.The layout has any relation with the default layout?And I have defined sections in every layout file by using the same section names.the default layout has the same code of section:
    @if (IsSectionDefined("HeadJs"))
        {
            RenderSection("HeadJs", false);
        }

Comment: Don't forget using @RenderBody() for all the HTML fragmentt not enclosed within sections.